# Network "wake on pattern" not working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wake-on-lan

Wake-on-LAN works to this PC, on WiFi and over the internet.

Wake-on-Pattern works if pinging the hostname from another computer, but not if pinging the IP or trying to connect to a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the network location had changed to "Public Network". When changed back to "Private / Home Network", the computer started waking upon connecting to services on it, as it did before.

Secondary problem, "Windows 7 does not wake on directed packets (for example, ping) which have been known to cause frequent and unnecessary wakes" so my tests were no good.

http://www.old-photo.com/pages/wake-on-lan-windows7.htm

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617165(v=ws.10).aspx